# How to figure out a backhand Database in a BDC (BDCM model)

Tags: sharepoint, bcs, bdc

I wanted to know how can one know which Database is a BDCM model using. I did some research and found that I can export the model from the central admin (which I did). Now that I have a model (abc.bcdm) to work with, I am not sure how use this to find out the database (external content type) its connecting to.

I found a good article here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736296(v=office.12).aspx) and I installed Business Data Catalog Definition Editor as well. However this software do not recognize .BDCM files.

I will really appreciate anyone's help. Thanks in advance.